# Google guava singleton Eventbus fires multiple times

Tags: java, gwt, guava, vaadin

I use vaadin + spring IOC + google guava eventbus. Resources recommends to use guava eventbus as singleton. But when I do that I have the following problem;

- Let's say  I run the application on 3 different browsers at the same time, so I have 3 different instances of my application.
- then for example when an I press a button on one browser and fire an event, I notice that my related listener method with the @subscribe annotation gets called 3 times!

Is this is a normal behaviour I would expect because I use eventbus as singleton? If not what is going on here? MainController is a spring managed bean with a a custom Vaadin Application Scope

```
class MainController{
  public MainController() throws DAOException, Exception {
    EventBusFactory.getEventBusInstance().register(this);
  }

  @Subscribe
  public void addFacetEvent(FacetAddedEvent event) throws DAOException {
    getTreeTableView().addToList(event.getData());
  }
} 

class EventBusFactory{
  public static EventBus getEventBusInstance() {
        if(eventBus==null){
            eventBus=new EventBus();
        }
        return eventBus;
    }
}
```

P.s I also hesitate in Vaadin should I to use guava eventbus or guava gwt event bus?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds...weird and unexpected.  Does your listener get _registered_ three times, or does the event get posted three times?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman my method with subscribe annotation gets called 3 times but event posted only one time

Comment: And how/where are you registering the listeners?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I updated the question, tnx

Comment: There are two possibilities: either the listener is registered three times, or the event is posted three times.  Your code doesn't give me enough data to figure out which is which.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman when I debug I can see its not posted three times, but listener gets called three times. But I am not sure how did I manage to register listener 3 times, when I create a new app instance I create a new MainControler object, should I also make MainController class singleton so its created only once? is that the way to use eventbus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: It's normal and expected behaviour in this configuration (you have three Vaadin Applications and hence three `MainController` instances managed with single `EventBus`).

---

By *custom Vaadin Application Scope* did you mean scope from [this Vaadin addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-stuff)?

Anyway, it's simple to reproduce your situation having prototype-scoped MainController bean and Vaadin App like this:

```
public class SandpitApplication extends Application {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SandpitApplication.class);

  // https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration#section-Spring+Integration-SpringContextHelperClass
  private SpringContextHelper ctx;

  @Override
  public void init() {
    // vaadin stuff
    setTheme("common");
    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Vaadin Sample Application");
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);

    // get your bean from spring
    log.info("start SandpitApplication@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()));
    ctx = new SpringContextHelper(this);
    // create application-wide bean
    final MainController mainController = ctx.getBean("mainController");

    mainWindow.addComponent(new Button("click to post", new Button.ClickListener() {
      @Override public void buttonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
        log.info("click on button");
        EventBusFactory.getEventBusInstance().post(
            new FacetAddedEventImpl("click-"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())));
        log.info(mainController);
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

and `MainController` class:

```
class MainController {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);

  public MainController() {
    log.info("creating MainController@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()));
    EventBusFactory.getEventBusInstance().register(this);
  }

  @Subscribe
  public void addFacetEvent(final FacetAddedEvent event) {
    final String signature = "MC@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) + ": ";
    log.info("addFacetEvent in " + signature + event);
    // getTreeTableViewBuilder returns extended ArrayList with fancy add
    getTreeTableViewBuilder().addFacetToList(signature + event.getData());
  }

  // plus other stuff like toString etc.
}
```

When you do the following:

1. Start the vaadin app in your browser (App#1).
2. Click the App1#button.
3. Start another app (App#2).
4. Click the App2#button
5. Go back to tab with App#1.
6. Click the App1#button.

you'll get the following output:

> start SandpitApplication@75a5555a
>   creating MainController@2e98f864
>   click on button // #1
>   addFacetEvent in MC@2e98f864: FacetAddedEventImpl@6b527dc6{data: click-13:42:45}
>   MainController@2e98f864{treeTableViewBuilder: [MC@2e98f864: click-13:42:45]}
>   start SandpitApplication@3f9e529
>   creating MainController@2f8d604f
>   click on button // #2
>   addFacetEvent in MC@2e98f864: FacetAddedEventImpl@36c1fc67{data: click-13:42:47}
>   addFacetEvent in MC@2f8d604f: FacetAddedEventImpl@36c1fc67{data: click-13:42:47}
>   MainController@2f8d604f{treeTableViewBuilder: [MC@2f8d604f: click-13:42:47]}
>   click on button // #1
>   addFacetEvent in MC@2e98f864: FacetAddedEventImpl@42d32028{data: click-13:42:49}
>   addFacetEvent in MC@2f8d604f: FacetAddedEventImpl@42d32028{data: click-13:42:49}
>   MainController@2e98f864{treeTableViewBuilder: [MC@2e98f864: click-13:42:45, MC@2e98f864: click-13:42:47, MC@2e98f864: click-13:42:49]}

You should now see that singleton `EventBus` is managing two application-wide `MainController` beans and each is recieving event (because it's resolved by global `EventBus`).

Trying to guess what do you want to achieve, I'd say that you need create application-wide event bus bean:

```
<bean id="eventBus" class="com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus"
    scope="vaadinApplication" />
```

---

About P.S.: We use standard Guava in our Vaadin project extensively, no need for GWT version.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I will try what you have suggested